# GCP cloud function - Could not find kubectl on the path

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

i'm writing this Google Cloud Function (Python)

```
def create_kubeconfig(request):
    subprocess.check_output("curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash | echo "" ",stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True )
    os.system("./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh")
    os.system("gcloud init")
    os.system("curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.17.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl")

    os.system("gcloud container clusters get-credentials **cluster name** --zone us-west2-a --project **project name**")
    os.system("gcloud container clusters get-credentials **cluster name** --zone us-west2-a --project **project name**")
    conf = KubeConfig()
    conf.use_context('**cluster name**')
```

when i run the code it gives me the error 
**'Invalid kube-config file. ' kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.**

help me to solve it please

Comment: Are you trying to run this code inside a Cloud Function?

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, this is part of the cloud function code

Comment: @JohnHanley this two rows unnecessary just tried to solve the problem in some way
    os.system("./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh")
    os.system("gcloud init")
it doesn't helped

Comment: @KrisDEV, keep in mind that you are on serverless environment. You don't know what is installed on the underlying servers, because it's not your sever, it's serverless! Even if it works today, it could not work tomorrow! You can only rely to your code, not to the server environment! In short, never use os call in serverless environment (Cloud Function and AppEngine standard)!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i understood it today, but i dont know how to deal with it, i have to deploy a yaml files to create pods and services, and i have to create a cloud function for that, and i cant find anything that can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reach programmatically the K8S API. You have the description of the [API in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17)

But it's not easy and simple to perform. However, here some inputs for achieving what you want.

First, get the GKE master IP
[image]

Then you can access to the cluster easily. Here for reading the deployment

```
    import google.auth
    from google.auth.transport import requests
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
    session = requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)
    response = session.get('https://34.76.28.194/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments', verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json())
```

For creating one, you can do this

```
    import google.auth
    from google.auth.transport import requests
    credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
    session = requests.AuthorizedSession(credentials)
    with open("deployment.yaml", "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
    response = session.post('https://34.76.28.194/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments', data=data,
                            headers={'content-type': 'application/yaml'}, verify=False)
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json())
```

According with the object that you want to build, you have to use the correct file definition and the correct API endpoint. I don't know a way to apply a whole `yaml` with several definition in only one API call.

Last things, be sure to provide the [correct GKE roles](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/iam) to the Cloud Function service Account

**UPDATE**

Another solution is to use Cloud Run. Indeed, with Cloud Run and thanks to the Container capability, you have the ability to install and to call system process (it's totally open because [your container runs into a GVisor sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#sandbox), but most of common usages are allowed)

The idea is the following: use a gcloud SDK base image and deploy your application on it. Then, code your app to perform system calls.

Here a working example in Go

Docker file

```
FROM golang:1.13 as builder

# Copy local code to the container image.
WORKDIR /app/
COPY go.mod .
ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN go mod download

COPY . .

# Perform test for building a clean package
RUN go test -v ./...
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o server

# Gcloud capable image
FROM google/cloud-sdk

COPY --from=builder /app/server /server
CMD ["/server"]
```

Note: The image cloud-sdk image is heavy: 700Mb

The content example (only the happy path. I remove error management, and the stderr/stdout feedback for simplifying the code)

```
    .......
// Example here: recover the yaml file into a bucket
    client,_ := storage.NewClient(ctx)
    reader,_ := client.Bucket("my_bucket").Object("deployment.yaml").NewReader(ctx)
    content,_:= ioutil.ReadAll(reader)
// You can store locally the file into /tmp directory. It's an in-memory file system. Don't forget to purge it to avoid any out of memory crash
    ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/file.yaml",content, 0644)
// Execute external command
// 1st Recover the kube authentication
    exec.Command("gcloud","container","clusters","get-credentials","cluster-1","--zone=us-central1-c").Run()
// Then interact with the cluster with kubectl tools and simply apply your description file
    exec.Command("kubectl","apply", "-f","/tmp/file.yaml").Run()
    .......
```

Comment: hi thanks a lot for your answer, i'll glad for some more help: i have different files in one folder, some of them are deployments, some of them statefulsets and some of them services, i want to deploy the file, withoun choosing the type, like this `namespaces/default/deployments` is there a way to do it

Comment: okey - so after trying to deploy the yaml file as you suggested i have the next problem:
`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
  namespace: zookeeper`
this is part of my yaml file, so i wrote: _response = session.post('https://3.1.1.1/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/zookeeper/deployments', data=data, headers={'content-type': 'application/yaml'}, verify=False)_ instead of your suggestion and i got the next error: **409 Client Error: Conflict for url: https://34.94.20.3/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/zookeeper/deployments**
how can i solve it?

Comment: there is no secret. I got a look to [kubectl code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/) and the file are parsed, there is a strategy for apply the definition in the correct order but each API is called separately. As said in my answer "it's not easy and simple". About your error, take care of the GKE cluster version, the yaml `apiVersion` definition and the endpoint that you call.

Comment: [https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/] how can i use it? i don't really understand

Comment: `kubectl` is the best tool to talk with K8S master. you simply perform a `kubectl apply -f file` and all the file is applied to your cluster, the correct API called and in the correct order. It's open source and you can have a look on how it is build. You can't use it in Python and on Cloud Function. In Go, dirty things could be possible, but not recommended.

Comment: it's so confusing, i  have different yaml files, part of them have different apiVersion, 
do you know if the changing of apiVersion can ruin something in the service?

Comment: I achieved a dirty solution with Cloud Run (in Go, but really easy to achieve the same in Python). I use gcloud and kubectl commands directly inside the code. Are you interested?

Comment: yes, really intrested, cause i tryed to use it in the code with os.system - but the error was that kubectl not found - because of that i tried this way with "gcloud"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `gcloud` inside the Cloud Function (and attempting to install it on every request, which will significantly increase the runtime of your function), you should use the [`google-cloud-container`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-container/) client library to make the same API calls directly from Python, for example:

```py
from google.cloud import container_v1

client = container_v1.ClusterManagerClient()

project_id = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID'
zone = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ZONE'

response = client.list_clusters(project_id, zone)
```

Comment: i want to deploy (kubectl apply -f) some yaml files to the cluster - do you know what command can help me if i use your suggested solution?

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, perhaps [`update_cluster()`](https://googleapis.dev/python/container/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.container_v1.ClusterManagerClient.update_cluster)?

Comment: i have a cluster with few nodes - each node have few workloads - with yaml configuration. 
at the end of the day i delete all the deployments and services from the node, and at the morning i want to "turn on" the system again - locally i just write "kubectl apply -f %path". i want to do the same thing via the cloud function